# Search like on stackoverflow using PHP

Tags: php, search

How can we create a search, merely simple than stack overflow, like for example when i type user: flash, it search for users, tag: flash, it search for tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably want to parse the first term before the " : " to use as the type identifier.
Once that's determined, look up by the table associated to the identifier by the term succeeding the first instance of " : " in the string

```
$searched = $_POST['searchterm'];
$identifier = explode(":", $searched)[0];
$lookup = null;
switch ($identifier){
   case 'tag':
      $lookup = 'tag';
      break;
   case 'user':
      $lookup = 'user';
      break;
   case 'default':
      // whatever you want if user selects unsupported term
      break;
}
```